# Searching in One to Many

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a system that have a Users table and a Books table.
I need to implement a Users search, and a results page showing all Users and all Books belonging to each user.

1. Currently, I'm using **GROUP_CONCAT** to get the Books of each User.
2. Alternatively, using **LEFT JOIN** brings **duplicate** results; Then I have to manipulate the data in PHP(is this 'better'?) Off course, I can't use GROUP BY as I need all Books.
3. I don't have any problems with GROUP_CONCAT, but now I need to filter by Book's and putting 'WHERE books.name like "% name%"' will filter the GROUP_CONCAT result, then showing just the searched book in the filter(while I need **all users books**)

Which is the best method to do a search with One-to-Many results in PHP / MySQL?

Comment: how with interface or the ux design you have built? you only have 1 input text or you give an option with checkbox or radio button?

Comment: Two inputs: 'Book name' or 'User name'.

Comment: I think you can simply follow what you have already done with your user->books, which it GROUP_CONCAT, make it for books->user